# iPhone : How to put activity indicator on particular Tabbar click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

In my app I have 5 tab bar. On particular tab bar click I want to display activity indicator for some time.

For Example,

I have 5 tab bars in which one is `Photos`.

Now when user click on this `Photos`, It should display activity indicator for sometime and then display that Photosview.

How do I achieve this? Even I dont know How to determine which tab is selected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController%3adidSelectViewController%3a) delegate method.

Comment: I tried this but it is not calling this method. Do I need anything else for this ?

Comment: @Devang: have you set yourself as the tab bar controller's delegate?

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried using the debugger? You haven't posted any code or other information.

Comment: I have set this delegate in my .h file(Appdelegate file) `UITabBarControllerDelegate,UITabBarDelegate`  and I am calling the - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"View Controller : %@",viewController.nibName);
} this method in .m file (App delegate)

Comment: Simply putting UITabBarControllerDelegate in the .h file isn't enough. You have to actually set self.tabBarController.delegate = self;.

Comment: @jtbandes let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1644/discussion-between-devang-and-jtbandes)

Comment: So I need to write this coding in app delegate ?